# MVC4 Custom OnActionExecuting Global.asx Filter is not being Triggered

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a Global filter that will run for every action I have if the user is logged in. From what I have read there are two steps necessary. First, add the new filter within the Global.asx file.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    //I added this
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new NotificationFilter());
    }
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
}
```

Then I have to create the filter itself in the filters folder.

```
public class NotificationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    { //Breakpoint here is never triggered
        //This code doesn't work, but it's what I want to do
        if (WebSecurity.CurrentUserId > 0)
        {
            var notificationCount = db.Notifications.GroupBy(i => i.UserID).Count();
            if (notificationCount > 99)
            {
                ViewBag.Notifications = "99+";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Notifications = notificationCount;
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

How can I make this work? Is there a better way? I can add this to all the controllers and it works, that's just less than ideal.

Comment: Great question, @Jed. Why you need an action to occur for every logged in user for every page?

Comment: @Dave I think I need one so I can get the number of notifications that users has on any page they may be on, if they are logged in.

Comment: OIC. 2nd question: would you want the number of notifications to be set at render time or real time? Notice on Stack or FB you see your notifications change after render...

Comment: Ideally they change after render, more responsive, however, I've figured I would start with something easier, because I really barely understand what I am doing. If you can direct me to something that would be awesome though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same experience. you can build a BaseController class and put the filter definition in it. Then all of your controllers must be inherited from BaseController class. So you don't have to use filter class in all controllers.

something like this:

```
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {

        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
         ...
         }
    }
```

In controllers:

```
public class SampleController : BaseController
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: Where do you create the BaseController? In filters or the Global.asx file or somewhere else? Sorry pretty new to all of this.

Comment: No its an individual class that you can put it anywhere.

Comment: I would've thought acttion filter. this is much better answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code for your problem :

```
public class ParentController : Controller
{

   protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
       /* take current action*/
       action = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];

       /* check if your action have your filter */
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(action) && Methods.
                    Where(
                           method => method.Name == action
                           &&        method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(/* your filter name */), true).Length > 0
                    ).Count() > 0)
          {
            // do your work    
          }


   }
}
```

and

```
public class YourController : ParentController 
{

  // implementation of your controller
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jed, from what I understand you want all your pages to behave the same way and render notifications for authenticated users.

I suggest, within your _layout, you place a top left Div and jquery Ajax call (you can push the jquery into an alert.js file later).

```
    <div id='divNotifications'></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#divNotifications').load('Notifications/UserNotifications');
       }
    </script>
```

within your Notifications Controller have UserNotifications method returning :

```
public JsonResult AjaxUserNotifications()
{

    Notifications Notifications = new GetNotifications();

    return Json(Notifications, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

at first I recommend you make this render once as proof of functionality, then I suggest you make it a recurring call.

[How to constantly check for new message with setInterval without constantly notifying user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600327/how-to-constantly-check-for-new-message-with-setinterval-without-constantly-noti)

this stack thread goes into how to make Ajax calls repeat at time intervals.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to use little view and SignalR for push notifications.